# Calculate x,y line terminiating point of section of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a Cartesian plane running from -41 to 41 on the x and y axes and a circle centered on 0,0 with a radius of 41 divided up into a number of sections of different areas.  I know the percentage area of each section (ie: section 1 is 16.1% of the total area of the circle, section 2 is 13% of the total circle, etc -- think pie chart).

I need to calculate the x and y coordinates of the circumference points for each of the dividing lines of the section.

I am trying to programatically draw a 'pie chart' by dividing the circle into a number of points on he circumference from 0,0.

Here is my calculated data:

[image]

Comment: Are you given that the first section begins at $(41,0)$? It seems like unless you are given some starting point, the solution set would be closed under rotations.

Comment: By section, you mean sector right?

Comment: @Orangutango The first section begins at 0,41

Comment: Do you have knowledge of Trigonometry? because your question is pretty simple and the basic trigonometric functions are exactly what you need.

Comment: @OmerPT I did about 20 years ago and have been trying to recall based off of posts on here.  From what I could gather, if i could find the angle of each section, the cos(angle) = x and the sin(angle) = y.  I attempted to multiple the percentage of each sector times 360, since there are 360 degress in a circle.  I figured that each one of these would be the individual angle of the sector, and I could add all of the previous angles to get the current total angle

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSector.html, 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html

Comment: Exactly, just don't forget that cos and sin are for the unit circle, your circle has a radius of 41 so you need to multiply the trigonometric functions by 41.

Comment: when I take the sin and the cos of each however, I never end up with any y values which are negative. yes; I am multiplying the sin and cos by 41.

Comment: Sin should be negative for angles more than 180 and less than 360, cos for angles between 90 and 180 degrees.

Make sure your programming language uses degrees and not radians.

Comment: @OmerPT take a look at my data, does that seem right?  Can i assume that when I draw a line, it will be from 0,0 to cos(angle), sin(angle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle represented by each percentage is just that percentage multiplied by $2 \pi$.  So if the first sector starts at $(41,0)$, horizontal to the left, and we go clockwise, the terminating point for that sector is $(41 \cos (0.161\cdot 2 \pi), -41 \sin (0.161\cdot 2 \pi)) \approx (21.75,-34.75)$, where the minus sign comes from going clockwise instead of counterclockwise.  The total angle of sectors $1$ and $2$ is then $0.291$ of the circle, so the ending point will be $(41 \cos (0.291\cdot 2 \pi), -41 \sin (0.291\cdot 2 \pi))\approx(-10.45,-39.58)$

Comment: Thank you very much for an example using my data. It really helped crytalize the procedure.